# How to click the enter button?

Tags: python, selenium

I can't make the code click on the enter button to go to the next page, so far I've tried:

XPATH

LINK_TEXT

PARTIAL_LINK_
TEXT

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located

I'm using selenium

Link: [Site](https://business.facebook.com/creatorstudio/home)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
Ok, for selenium I use web-driver-manager, basically, you need setting according to your browser. Search for more details in the official doc https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/

I use a code for the browser Edge,

## Install two libraries

```py
pip install web-driver-manager selenium
```

My code for Microsoft Edge. I test and run correctly for me.

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service as EdgeService
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

service_ = EdgeService(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install())
browser_ = webdriver.Edge(service=service_)

browser_.get("https://business.facebook.com/creatorstudio/home")

time.sleep(4)

browser_.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/span/div/div/div').click()

time.sleep(2)

print("Finished")
```

Comment: yes I'm using selenium, I tried your suggestion and had no result, I also posted the website link.